# Get current logged in username

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, directoryservices, windows-identity

I want to get the user name of the current logged in user. I am using the below code but it returns the user whose credentials are used in IIS application pool identity. The mvc website is deployed on a server.

I have used

`string userid = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();`

`string userid = Environment.UserName;`

`string userid = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.GivenName.ToString();`

`string userid = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString()`

But nothing seems to give me correct answer.

I need to get user name in the constructor of the `HomeController`.

Below is my web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: try this...HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Comment: I tried this but its returning empty string.

Comment: My fault actually. HttpContext worked. I was trying to check while debugging so was getting empty string,  but when I deployed and checked the user name it gave the correct result. Can you post your answer so that I can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just instead of

```
string userid = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString()
```

use this,this will work fine

```
string userid = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString()
```

Comment: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString() is working fine. Just that while debugging it would only show empty string but if we deploy the site then it works perfectly.